# My method doesn't remember things from other methods

Tags: python, class, oop

My `question.info()` method doesn't remember anything from the ask `question.ask()` method.

I assume this is because it refresh's from the initial function, but when I delete where the variables are first defined in the initial function, it returns a big error.

This is my code:

```
import time
class question:

    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.time = 0
        self.attempt = 0
        self.correct = False

    def ask(self):
        start = time.clock()
        self.attempt = input(self.question)

        self.time = time.clock() - start
        if self.attempt == str(self.answer):
            self.correct = True 

    def info(self):
        print("Question:", self.question)
        print("Answer:", self.answer)
        print("Attempt:", self.attempt)
        print("Correct:", self.correct)
        print("time taken:", self.time)


class test:

    def __init__(self, qList):
        self.qList = qList
    def doTest(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.qList)):
            question(self.qList[i][0],self.qList[i][1]).ask()
            question(self.qList[i][0],self.qList[i][1]).info()

basicMath = [
    ["what is 1",1],
    ["what is 2",2],
    ["what is 3",3],
    ["what is 4",4],
    ["what is 5",5],
    ]

task = test(basicMath)
task.doTest()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create *separate `question` instances*:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.qList)):
    question(self.qList[i][0],self.qList[i][1]).ask()
    question(self.qList[i][0],self.qList[i][1]).info()
```

You call `question()` twice there. Create one instead:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.qList)):
    q = question(self.qList[i][0],self.qList[i][1])
    q.ask()
    q.info()
```

as the separate instances keep their state separate otherwise.

You should really just loop directly over `self.qList` rather than use `range()` here:

```
for question_text, answer in self.qList:
    q = question(question_text, answer)
    q.ask()
    q.info()
```